# Setting up configure/makevars for libcouchbase in R?

Tags: r, build, couchbase, autoconf

I am creating a new R package where I would like to call an external c library([libcouchbase](https://github.com/couchbase/libcouchbase)).

My problem is how to get the package build system to find the libraries during linking. I am using a linux/ubuntu like system.

This is what I had so far do :

#### create an configure.ac

```
AC_INIT(rcouchbase, version-0.1)
AC_CHECK_LIB([couchbase], [lcb_create], [],
             [AC_MSG_ERROR(Failed to locate libcouchbase >= 2.0.0)])
COUCHBASE_LIBS="$LIBS"
AC_SUBST(COUCHBASE_LIBS)
AC_OUTPUT(src/Makevars)
```

#### generate a configure using autoconf

```
system("autoconf configure.ac > configure | chmod +x configure")
```

#### create a makevars.in

```
# set by configure
COUCHBASE_LIBS = @COUCHBASE_LIBS@
PKG_LIBS = $(COUCHBASE_LIBS)
```

#### build my package:

When I build my package, the configure file sucess to find the

```
==> R CMD INSTALL --no-multiarch --with-keep.source rcouchbase
```

Here the some significant output:

==> R CMD INSTALL --no-multiarch --with-keep.source rcouchbase

```
* installing to library ‘/home/agstudy/R/packages’
* installing *source* package ‘rcouchbase’ ...
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking for lcb_create in -lcouchbase... yes
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating src/Makevars
make: Nothing to be done for `all'.
** libs
installing to /home/agstudy/R/packages/rcouchbase/libs
** R
** preparing package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** testing if installed package can be loaded
Error in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...) : 
  unable to load shared object '/home/agstudy/R/packages/rcouchbase/libs/rcouchbase.so':
  /home/agstudy/R/packages/rcouchbase/libs/rcouchbase.so: undefined symbol: lcb_destroy
Error: loading failed
Execution halted
ERROR: loading failed
* removing ‘/home/agstudy/R/packages/rcouchbase’

Exited with status 1.
```

So does anyone know what I should add to my makevars/config file to solve the linkng problem?

### EDIT add shared library dependencies:

```
ldd libcouchbase.so
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff0a7fe000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007fea0a26e000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007fea0a06a000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fea09ca1000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fea0a7c5000)
```

Comment: Your tags are 'all wrong'. This really is just a question about autoconf.  You could try to see what a few of my packages to here, alongside some autoconf tutorials.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel I removed the rcpp tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say `COUCHBASE_LIBS="$LIBS"`, who is filling in `$LIBS` for you?

At a first step, try to decompose the issue. You should us pieces: `src/Makevars.in`, but 
not the generated `src/Makevars`. Does it have the correct library listed?

Also, look at / show us `R CMD INSTALL ...` output. Is there a link step with the library?
What you posted suggests not as the `lcb_destroy` symbol is missing.

In case you want to learn about Autotools / Automake, I have gone back to [this (older) tutorial](http://seul.org/docs/autotut/) a few times; you may find it useful.

*Edit:* You are still confused. We don't want to see `ldd libcouchbase`; we presume that one is fine. *Your* package does not load so we need *its* linking step and *its* ldd output.

I.e. my RQuantLib package ends its `R CMD INSTALL` on

```
g++ -shared -o RQuantLib.so [many .o files removed] \
           -L/usr/lib -lQuantLib -L/usr/lib/R/lib -lR
```

which clearly shows that it does link with the (required) QuantLib library.

Comment: LIBS is filled `AC_CHECK_LIB`. In my case I get `-lcoucbase`.

Comment: Ok then--that seems like good use of autoconf. But is `libcouchbase.*` in one of your system library directories?  Is R actually linking with it?

Comment: yes in `/usr/local/lib/` I have all *.so.  and R suceed to find my headerslaos when I use `#include <libcouchbase/couchbase.h>`

Comment: Please show the linking step of `R CMD INSTALL` and try `ldd` on the resulting `.so` library.

Comment: I added ldd output but I don't understand the linking STEP? I am using R studio. Maybe I should add something to its build options.

Comment: Hit the 'Build & Reload' button / menu in RStudio. There will be compile steps, and link steps. Look at the link step. Does it include the Couchbase library? Also see my edited question.

Comment: I modify my question to include the exact output of RCMD INSTALL... I don't see any link step, just a build one. I don't see any call for couchebase or -lcouchbase.

Comment: See `make: Nothing to be done for `all'.` You need to remove the existing `src/*.so` to have it rebuilt.

Comment: oh my bad! I should remove *.so ! ( I don't know if I have this behavior in windows). I have another error now ` Unable to load module "Rcouchbase"` . but I think it is related to my cpp code. my link is `g++ -shared -o rcouchbase.so rcouchbase.o -lcouchbase -L/usr/lib/R/lib -lR`

Comment: `Unable to load module "Rcouchbase"` is telling you that your code cannot be loaded.  From here, we cannot tell what the error is.

Comment: Thank dirk. I will investigate in my own for the moment and see my c++  code. I think the link problem is fixed( I hope so). I will accept this answer. thanks again.